# Windows Server 2008 R2 C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe execution log (or monitoring) to locate file processing its high CPU usage

Tags: windows, perl, logging, server, cpu

We have software written in perl 5 that users access online through a windows 2008 server.

C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe is executing a file that causes high CPU processing indefinately. In our experience we've analyzed task manager and resource manager and it is very 'shadowy': the data changes too fast and there's not a real correlation to what file is causing the issue.

We'd like to correlate which file has been called to run when the CPU is maxing out at 100% for an extended period of time.

If C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe is running then is there a way to determine what it is executing?

We've looked into the 'Overview', 'CPU' and 'Disk' of the resource manager. The CPU tab doesn't tell us the file name whilethe Disk and Overview tabs won't show cpu processing.

Comment: How is the perl interpreter `perl.exe` started?

Comment: Web requests through perl's CGI library, these pages access a database, write interfaces from various perl files. There is user(s) accessing a perl file where there exists the problem in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The command line (including arguments) is available via WMI.

```
>wmic process where "name like '%perl%'" get ProcessId,CommandLine
CommandLine   ProcessId
perl  foo.pl  9900
```

```
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name like '%perl%'" `
   | Select-Object ProcessId,CommandLine

ProcessId CommandLine
--------- -----------
     9900 perl  foo.pl
```

If you prefer a GUI, you can use [Process Explorer]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) (from Microsoft).

[image: Screenshot of a toolip showing <code>perl.exe</code> executing <code>foo.pl</code>]

[image: Screenshot of the more detailed properties dialog]